# is there any way to do `index * corresponding item in list` faster than looping through it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code here:

```
a = [1,5,6,7,11,15]
for x in range(len(a)):
    total += (x+1)*a[x]
```

What I am trying to do is have total equal the total of the (index of a number +1) * (the number itself) iterated through the entire list.
So `total = 1x1 + 2x5 + 3x6 + 4x7 + 5x11 + 6x15` or `total = 202`

what I have is apparently "too slow" of a way to achieve this... Is there a faster way to achieve the same effect without using imported libraries?

EDIT: Apologies, list `a` was supposed to be sorted from lowest to highest. I forgot to do that for the example. And also does this count as a pattern?

Comment: What ***precisely*** does "apparently too slow" mean? (How many items will be in the list, and how fast does it need to run, on what hardware?)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sum()` function along with `enumerate()`.

```
total = sum(i * item for i, item in enumerate(a, 1))
```

The second argument to `enumerate()` is the first value of `i`, so you don't have to add 1.

However, in my test this is only about 10% faster than your loop with the short list. The benefit gets better as `a` gets longer. When I increased it to 54 elements, `sum()` took 75% as long as the loop.

Comment: Unfortunately this still fast enough... is there any other way?

Comment: How fast is "fast enough"? Most of the expense is all the multiplications and additions, I don't see how to get rid of them.

Comment: Unless there's a known pattern to the numbers rather than it being an arbitrary list. Then you can probably figure out an equation for the result (just like the sum of 1 to N is (N+1)*N/2)

Comment: If that's the case, the proper place to ask would be [math.se].

Comment: does a sorted list count a enough of a pattern? because the number pattern is user-input and I have no way of knowing the numbers beforehand

Comment: No, it needs to be a mathematical sequence of some kind, i.e. there needs to be a function to calculate the Nth element. And before the edit, your list wasn't even sorted, it had all the odd numbers followed by the even numbers.

Comment: A desperate way of removing multiplication would result in many more additions, such as something like; `sum(sum(a[i:]) for i in range(len(a)))`

Comment: @MatBailie Not to mention all the allocation of list slices. I would guess this would be orders of magnitude slower because of that.

Comment: `x=0; sum((x:=x+i) for i in reversed(a))`? (I'd still assume the overhead of `:=` is greater than `*`, but I'm waiting for a bus and pondered alternatives :)